# Minimum number of vertices in a $k$-chromatic graph of odd girth $g$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

The *odd girth* of a graph $G$ is defined as the minimum length of an odd cycle in $G$. Let $n_g(k)$ denote the minimum number of vertices in a $k$-chromatic graph of odd girth $g$. What are the known upper and lower bounds on $n_g(k)$?

It is known that the order of magnitude of $n_5(k)$ is $k^2 \log k$; this corresponds to $k$-chromatic triangle-free graphs. Is anything known for higher values of $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-012-0882-4?LI=true) paper (also available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.3271)) we show that a graph having no odd cycles of length $\leq 2r-1$ and having at most
$$
  \frac{(k+r)(k+r+1)\dots(k+2r-1)}{2^{r-1}r^r}
$$
vertices is properly $k$-colorable. This provides an upper bound.

Another upper bound is provided by the paper by Kierstead, Szemeredi, and Trotter (see reference [4] in the above paper --- this also contains some upper bounds!).

On the upper bounds --- there are several different examples. One is the Schrijver subgraph of the Kneser graph (see [6] in the mentioned paper, or discussion on the first page), another one is the iterated (generalized) Mycielski construction applied to $C_{2r+1}$; see a relate discussion in

> A. Gyarfas, T. Jensen, and M. Stiebitz, On graphs with strongly independent color-classes. // Journal of Graph Theory 46 (2004), 1–14.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! The expression you give provides a lower bound, not an upper bound, right? So, as far as you know, the best upper bound comes from Schrijver graphs?

Comment: Right,, it provides a lower bound. Both Schrijver and (generalized) Mycielski provide an upper bound which seems to be  tight in the exponent of $k$ (when $k$ is large compared with $r$), due to Kierstead--Szemeredi--Trotter. For other relations of parameters, I do not remember... By the way, you may find some extra links to some results for specific series of parameters in the Intro of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.8086.pdf